# Android check for system date to change then run code

Tags: android, alarmmanager

What is the best way to go about running code immediately on system date change?

Currently I am trying to set the wallpaper on a device based on the date. If the date changes, I will set the wallpaper to a new image. My code for getting and setting the wallpaper all works. I am trying to setup an alarm manager but I can't get it to work. How can I make sure my alarm is set to set the wallpaper each time the date changes and immediately.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

                alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
                alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, 0);

                alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

                // Execute DownloadImage AsyncTask
                new DownloadImage().execute(URL);

                try {
                    WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).setBitmap(bm);
                }
                catch (  IOException e) {

                }

            }


         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register you broadcast receiver in manifest file with this action:

```
android:action="ACTION_DATE_CHANGED"
```

Read the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) for more.

Comment: Alright I have it detecting system date change now but I am getting an error trying to run my code

Comment: is there a way to set the wallpaper on a device from OnReceive()? My async task works in my activity but I want to set the wallpaper when the action change is noticed by the device without opening the application.

Comment: Start a service in onReceive() of BroadcastRecceiver. Services owrk in the background. Read more here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732812/android-app-to-change-wallpaper-at-regular-intervals-using-timer

Comment: Thanks. very helpful advice. I will check this out so I will use alarm manager and then on receive I will run my service.

Comment: If my first answer answered your first question then please mark it as "correct"  :)

Comment: I still haven't been able to get anything to work. My main activity when you open the application it works. It sets the wallpaper automatically but when I try to set up alarm manager and broadcast receiver. I can get it to show me a message onreceive but when I try to run my async task it fails.

Comment: Don't run an asynctask. In onReceive of broadcast receiver start a Servicce. In the Service class do the wallpaper changing tasks.